# Unix shell scripting with counter

Tags: unix, counter

i am new to unix shell scripting

I need to write a shell script that should increment a variable value (numeric) and when i run the script next time the variable should take the incremented value and it should increment once agian
 any help in this would be really thankful

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
vale=`expr 0000000000 + 1`
ed -s $0 <<EOT
1s/ ........../`printf ' %010d' $vale`/
w
q
EOT
echo $vale
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by some explanation I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need for the value of the variable to persist somehow. One way is to save it to a file.

```
outputfile="~/variable.txt"

value=`cat $outputFile`

newValue=`expr $value + 1`

echo $newValue > $outputFile
```